# LSApplicationLaunchProhibited App Submission Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, imessage

I am trying to submit an update for iMessage extension with a main app. I archived the main app and tried to submit, but it gave me this weird message.

[Weird Submission Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ9kC.png)